# Translating touch gestures to mouse gestures

Tags: c#, xna, windows-runtime, monogame, gestures

Here's a sample of some code I have to handle tpouch gestures:

```
public void HandleInput()
{
    TouchPanel.EnabledGestures =
       GestureType.FreeDrag | GestureType.DragComplete | GestureType.DoubleTap | GestureType.Tap;

    while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
    {
        GestureSample gs = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
        switch (gs.GestureType)
        {
             case GestureType.FreeDrag:
                 ...
                 break;

             case GestureType.DragComplete: 
                 ...
                 break;

             case GestureType.DoubleTap:    
                 ...
                 break;

             case GestureType.Tap:                    
                 ...
                 break;

 ...
```

This is written using monogame (i.e. XNA) and I belatedly realised that I wasn't handling mouse input for cases where the target machine (WinRT) didn't have touch capabilities.

So far, the only way I've come across of handling mouse gestures is as follows:

```
 MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
 Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);

 if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
    ...
```

I can see that it would be possible to achieve the same thing here, but I'd like to be lazy and cut a corner (and hopeful produce simpler code).  So, my question is twofold:

1. Is it possible to handle mouse "gestures"?
2. If it isn't, is there a way to convince XNA that mouse is actually touch (the simulator for Windows 8 does this very well).

Answer (score 0):

I think you really don't want to couple touch and mouse gestures. If your game uses multitouch then coupling them would be almost impossible. You would have to separate the touch styles in your code.

But if you really insist on coupling them, you could create your own wrapper class that will translate all the input to what you want and pass that on to your gameobjects. I.e. rather than using Mouse.GetState() -> MyGlobalInput.GetState() that will evaluate whether touch or mouse is available/used.

But remember: The user expects that touch input is different than mouse input since the experience is quite different, so it would imply that both cases have their own logic. Use a global setting for when you want to use mouse or touch ( or when both is available, let the user choose? ). Having their own logic will then allow you to build the gestures for mouse and touch more easily. This is also an architectural view/decision

Edit: also, if you are referring to the monogame `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch.GestureSample`, it takes just some vector2 positions that are the same as touch vector2 positions. You just need some smart translation for mouse  to touch input.